# Insert blank page in pdf with OpenPdf

Tags: scala, pdf, jpeg, openpdf

Hi I working on simple function which marge all jpg files and save them to pdf (with [openpdf](https://github.com/LibrePDF/OpenPDF)). Each image should be fitted to page, and between them I want to have one blank page. I already have:

```scala
def createFromImage(directory: String, targetFile: String): Unit = {
    logger.info(s"Create pdf from images in $directory.")
    val document = new Document()
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(targetFile))
    document.open()
    val resultFiles = new File(directory).listFiles().toList.map(_.getAbsolutePath)
    resultFiles.filter(x => x.contains(".jpg")).map {
      file =>
        import com.lowagie.text.Image
        val jpg: Image = Image.getInstance(file)
        document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4)
        val ratio: Float = PageSize.A4.getWidth / jpg.getWidth
        jpg.scalePercent(ratio * 100)
        document.add(jpg)
    }
    document.close()
    logger.info("Pdf created.")
  }
```

How to add blank page to `document`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a clean solution you need to use the `PdfWriter` instance, so first replace

```
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(targetFile))
```

by

```
val writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(targetFile))
```

Then add after `document.add(jpg)`:

```
document.newPage()
writer.setPageEmpty(false)
document.newPage()
```

The `writer.setPageEmpty(false)` is needed to make OpenPdf think the empty page is not empty because it ignores `document.newPage()` calls if it thinks the current page is completely empty.

Instead of `writer.setPageEmpty(false)` you can alternatively add some invisible content like an all-white image.

Comment: Thanks, it works :)